# Regex: number N followed by any N symbol

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that matches a number N followed by any N characters.
Those. 1n, 2dg, 6iut5.u
Please note that 49875 is also suitable.
Thought that (\d+).{\1} should work, but it seems to match strings like 3l{3}, 10k{10} ...

Comment: What is n symbol? ha?

Comment: Regex has no concept of "number". Get the first or first few characters, convert it to an integer and compare that with the length of the rest of the line. How to do that programmatically depends on the language, which hasn't been mentioned in the question.

Comment: What about: `(\d).+` It matces a start digit followed by anything.

Comment: Do you mean a number or a digit?

Comment: This counting can be done inside a Perl regex with code constructs. For others there is no way that matched text can be turned into a parameter like a range quantifier construct `{x,y}`

Answer (score 1):

The repetition count cannot be a back reference in any regex dialect I am familiar with. Either spell out the alternatives:

```
1.|
2..|
3...|
4....|
5.....|
...
```

(where I put in newlines just for legibility); or use code which evaluates the criterion in two passes:

```
import re

for match in re.finditer(r'(\d+)(.+)', text):
    if len(match.group(2)) == int(match.group(1)):
        print(match)
```

(The example uses Python; season to taste.)